# Random variable for market share

Tags: random, probability

I want to probabilistically represent the following situation: There are three competitors in a market, and between them, they share 100% of the market.

So to reflect this, I want three random variables X, Y and Z that are:

1. uniformly distributed between 0% and 100%; and also that
2. sum to 100%.

Condition 1 is easy - I just define three uniformly distributed (between 0% and 100%) and independent random variables X, Y and Z.

```
P(x < X) = x
P(y < Y) = y
P(z < Z) = z
```

Then for condition 2 (to get them to sum to 100%), I take my uniform X, Y and Z, and then define X', Y' and Z' as:

```
X' = X / (X + Y + Z)
Y' = Y / (X + Y + Z)
Z' = Z / (X + Y + Z)
```

So I now have three random variables which satisfy condition 2, but they no longer satisfy condition 1. (I can prove that X' is not uniformly distributed.)

Is there any way to define X', Y' and Z' so that they satisfy both conditions? Either using X, Y and Z or some other way?

Comment: Can't you just use `X+Y+Z=100%` ? What's the catch?

Comment: Sorry Elric, I don't understand your suggestion. If I define X, Y and Z as described in my question, then it is very unlikely that your equation holds true. How are you suggesting I make your equation hold true?

Comment: Ok, your answer suggests you don't want a mathematical definition, you want to implement this in some software? I would just write the sum statement, since it's a statement, it is true.

Comment: But you are just restating condition 2 of my question! I'm trying to define three random variables that meet that condition! By "define" I mean "define X, Y and Z" - ie for each one to come up with a formula for it like `P(t<T)`, as in the example in the question (which I then demonstrate doesn't cut it). So, I am looking for either a mathematical definition would suffice, or an algorithmic one. But a definition that is more than just restating the conditions I'm asking for it to satisfy!

Comment: To explain myself better with an analogy: if I were asking "find x such that 2x = 10", your answer is equivalent to saying "2x = 10", whereas the actual answer is "x = 5".

Comment: I've been thinking about it a lot. I think the answer to satisfy both conditions is no. Here is something I tried: https://i.imgur.com/YO1dqLh.png (the column names are hidden because I'm dummy). I tried other stuff, and found out that once the first number is defined, your options are reduced, since it's a sum, the latter ones to be selected must be smaller. I think your approach is the optimal one, breaking the problem with the intermediary variables.

Comment: Thank you @Elric - that's about as far as I've got as well, but I think correlation / copulas might have something to do with it. I like your idea of `X' = X`, `Y' = (1-X)Y` and `Z' = X-Y`, but it's interesting that there is no `Z`. Doesn't feel right that we are representing three uncertain things with only two random variables, but maybe there's another transform out there that could do it!